# cannot find -llibboost_regex in boost 1.62.0 in linux opensuse

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am just trying to run replace_regex_copy in my code. For that I have included regex.hpp file. At the start it showed some errors like Unreferenced includes something like that. I googled it, I found that need to include -llibboost_regex in the linker. But after including that I am getting linker error as cannot find -libboost_regex.

But I have libboost_regex.a and libboost_regex.so in boost/lib folder.

Eclipse configuration I made:
Under GCC C++ Linker:
Libraries (-l)      libboost_regex
Library Search Path (-L)     /boost/lib

Even I tried to give entire path with the file in Libraries(-l) too. But nothing helps.

Still am getting cannot find -llibboost_regex error. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The `lib` prefix is not part of the library name. Don't use it with the linker.

Comment: But the file name is libboost_regex

Comment: No the *file* name is e.g. `libboost_regex.so`. The *library* name is `boost_regex`. When linking you only tell the linker the *library* name. If you say you want to link with `libboost_regex` then the linker will search for a file named `liblibboost_regex.so`.

Comment: But the file name is libboost_regex. Thanks its working.. But can you let me know why it is working like this? I can find the file name prefixed with lib

Comment: Thank you very much.. Silly mistake..